# Display gif on imagebutton android

Tags: android

I was wondering if it is possible to display a gif animation on an image button. I followed the example on Android API BitmapDecode sample and can now display animated gifs on the canvas.

Is it possible to display this same gif on an imagebutton. I tried using the setBackgroundDrawable() and setImageDrawable() but it gives me an empty button.

```
@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
  setContentView(R.layout.test);
  ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ImageButton01);
  SampleView p=new SampleView(this);

  p.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
  p.buildDrawingCache();
      btn.setBackgroundDrawable(p.getBackground());

}
```

The SampleView() class is similar to the one provided in the [BitmapDecode sample](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/BitmapDecode.html) (i have removed all other code snippets and it now displays only gif animation)

Thanks,
New Guy.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should be possible just like it is with ImageViews - split up the animation into frames and then animate these frames using the android frame by frame animation. You might want to refer to http://www.app-solut.com/blog/2011/05/playing-animations-in-android/ for more information on how to use such a frame-by-frame animation